# Is it possible to create a single, long String of names from a for loop? (No lists/arrays)

Tags: java, string-concatenation

```
    System.out.println("How many teams are in this tournament?");
    no_of_teams=kb.nextInt();

    for(int x=1; x<=no_of_teams; x+=1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of team " + x);
        team=kb.next();
    }
```

I would like to have *team* contain all the user inputs, so I can then use String.split later on in the program to output the team names once again.

I asked my original question on Reddit but to no avail, it went like this:

> We have been asked to create a program which runs to collect data
>   based on a round robin soccer tournament for 'n' no. of teams. My
>   issue is when I must ask for all the team names at the beginning
>   (which I must) based on what no. of teams the user inputs of course, I
>   can do this with a for loop and the output is perfect:

*input the code from up above here*

> However, as I am sure you are aware, this
>   basically means that team will now just be stored as whichever team
>    name was entered last as the for loop caused it to be overwritten.
>    This is a problem because later down in the program you are meant to
>    then output all the different team names for when they are playing
>    against each other but team is only storing one team name. Using
>    team1, team2, team3, etc. is impractical because the user can enter an
>    infinite amount for the number of teams. We are not allowed to use
>    arrays because we have not covered them yet, and by all accounts the
>    way I am to get around this is to use String concatenation and while
>    loops, but I am unsure how this would apply. Any help would be
>    gratefully appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to concatenate some strings. Which is the delimiter? Which are the characters allowed for a team name?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question. Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: @R O M A N I A

 I don't even know what a delimiter is as we haven't covered them yet, but for the team name it's letters and spaces I suppose.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't allowed to use arrays or vectors or stacks or lists etc? This sounds like exactly the type of project you'd be given to exercise those. Using string concatenation for a problem like this is a bit like shaving with a spoon. You may get it to work, but you'll be left wondering "why"!

Comment: @John3136 Yeah we haven't covered either of them yet so we can't use them, I'm only a beginner

Comment: Something doesn't add up. All of the info given points to an exercise about collections but you say you can't use them. Is there any other relevant information given in the question?

Comment: A delimiter would be the character you would use to sepperate the names in the string so you could break them up later like a "-" or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can just append names to a String with an attached delimiter:

```
StringBuilder team = new StringBuilder();
for(int x=1; x<=no_of_teams; x+=1)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of team " + x);
    //this will add a - after each name, and then you could split on the - character
    team.append(kb.next()).append("-");
}
```

However, this is really not the best options. I would use an array to store names. The answer I gave t would return one big string, that you would have to split on the '-'.

After you got your string, you could split it by doing:

```
team.toString().split("-");
```

If you wanted to output all the team names you would do something like:

```
for(String aTeam :  team.toString().split("-")){
   System.out.println("Team Name: " + aTeam);
}
```

Comment: Not allowed to use arrays unfortunately, we have yet to cover them!

Comment: My answer doesn't include an array. It is a solution without an array. I simply stated that using an array is your best option @Michael

Comment: Oh I know yeah, I'm just saying, but thanks, we haven't looked at delimiters yet but your solution does make more sense

Comment: @Michael you should look up what a delimiter is. You really shouldn't wait for an instructor to go over that with you. This is the case with a number of things when it comes to programming. I understand an instructor not wanting you to use arrays at this point, but you shouldn't feel like you can't use anything he hasn't talked about. A delimiter isn't unique to programming

Comment: Maybe should mention `StringBuilder`

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Thanks a bunch! But how do I then use the String.split to output the team names?

Comment: @Michael honestly, from what I have read, you need to use arrays. If you are trying to store data for specific teams, you can't do that with one string. The best you can do is print out all the team names. But if you are trying to

Comment: consider `team.append(kb.next()).append("-");`

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Any ideas why wherever I have "split" it is underlined in red as an error

Comment: @Michael I updated things again, and it should be for the final time.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Wonderful! One more thing and I should be on my way, that outputs all the team names, is there anyway way to select certain team names to output, or must I use arrays for that?

Comment: @Michael you would have to use arrays to select a specific team. Hopefully down the road you'll be able to do that. But there isn't any way to select specific teams using a single array.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Ok, thanks anyway, appreciate the help

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I beg to differ ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible! You do not have to use `arrays` or `lists` provided by java for your convenience, even implicitly like the `split` method BlackHatSamurai provided in his answer. It's simple - you implement your own ArrayList! Well, ArrayList-like thing anyway.

```
class MyStringStringList { 
    private static final char delimeter = '%'; //just a character not in the input
    private String internalMemory = "";

    public void add(String s) {
        internalMemory += s + delimeter;
    }

    public String getAll() {
        return internalMemory;
    }

    public String get(int index) {
        int delimeterCount = 0;
        StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < internalMemory.length(); j++) {
            if (internalMemory.charAt(j) == delimeter) {
                if (delimeterCount == index) {
                    return currentWord.toString();
                } else {
                    delimeterCount++;
                    currentWord = new StringBuilder();
                }

            } else {
                currentWord.append(internalMemory.charAt(j));
            }
        }
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
}
```

I moved this code to a new class for clarity, but you could just paste the insides into your main class and use it from there.

Some usage:

```
MyStringStringList list = new MyStringStringList();
for (int x = 1; x <= no_of_teams; x += 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of team " + x);
    list.add(kb.next());
}
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_teams; i++) {
    System.out.println("Team number " + i+1 + ": " + list.get(i));
}
```

Do note, that only a crazy person would do that. Inefficient, probably buggy, incomplete feature-wise... But if you are not mistaken, and you were in fact prohibited from using the built-in array or collections that could be the "Your rules are stupid" solution your teacher deserves.